# Перевести время из одного часового пояса в другой

Tags: java, timezone

Здравствуйте. Пытался разобраться с часовыми поясами в Java, но так и не нашел напрямую то, что мне нужно. Есть время в одном часовом поясе ("Atlantic/Azores"). Нужно перевести это в текущий часовой пояс пользователя. Можно ли это как-то сделать стандартными методами, не наворачивая в коде велосипедов? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: В java 8 добавили новую библиотеку работы со временем [`java.time`](http://goo.gl/SKGrtm). Для строки, будет что-то вроде `ZonedDateTime inLocalZone = ZonedDateTime.parse( "2016-04-12T00:00:00Z[Atlantic/Azores]" ).withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.systemDefault() )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//исходное время
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Atlantic/Azores"));
//в текущий часовой пояс
ZonedDateTime withLocalZone = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());
//без зоны
LocalDateTime localDateTime = withLocalZone.toLocalDateTime();

System.out.println(zdt);
System.out.println(withLocalZone);
System.out.println(localDateTime);
```

вывод

```
2016-04-12T19:05:44.093Z[Atlantic/Azores]
2016-04-12T22:05:44.093+03:00[Europe/Moscow]
2016-04-12T22:05:44.093
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но только сейчас осознал, что Android не поддерживает библиотеки Java 8. Можно ли как-то получить данный результат, используя более старые библиотеки?

Comment: @ahgpoug Тогда как в соседнем ответе. Можно еще попробовать библиотеку Joda Time подключить (сам не пробовал, тем более на андроиде).

Comment: Хорошо, я попробую. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Внутренне представление даты в java хранится в UTC, поэтому имеет смысл переводить дату в нужный часовой пояс уже при выводе пользователю.

```
// создаем Новый год на Азорских островах 
DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dfm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Atlantic/Azores"));
Date d = dfm.parse("2016-01-01 00:00:00");

// будем выводить дату в ISO-формате   
DateFormat iso = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

// дата на Азорских островах
iso.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Atlantic/Azores"));
System.out.println(iso.format(d)); // 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000-0100

// местная дата
iso.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
System.out.println(iso.format(d)); // 2016-01-01T04:00:00.000+0300
```

---

PS. [Все, что нужно знать о датах в Java](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php)

Comment: Что-то не похоже чтобы оно в UTC хранилось. Может быть когда-нибудь. На днях тоже разбирался с датой-временем. Ваще бардак какой-то. В отладчике netbeans-а если посмотреть на Date, то открывается куча полей. Есть какой-то offset подозрительно совпадающий с разницей в миллисекундах моего времени и UTC 28800000. Java 7-ой версии. А везде пишут, что нет там в Date никакой таймзоны. Брехня

Answer (score 0):

- fromDateTime - откуда (LocalDateTime/ZoneDateTime)
- fromZone - из какой зоны (ZoneId )
- toZone - в какую зону (ZoneId)

**`ZonedDateTime.of(fromDateTime, fromZone).withZoneSameInstant(toZone);`**

**`.toLocalDateTime(); // можно добавить если нужен LocalDateTime();`**